# Is there an exponential distribution family whose convolution closure is dense?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

Let the convolution closure of a family of distributions be all convolutions of finite sets of distributions in the family.

Is there a parametric exponential distribution family (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) whose convolution closure is dense in the space of all probability functions with the $L_1$ norm? (or some other norm?)

My initial thoughts are that such a family, if it exists, can't have only symmetric or log-concave functions, as convolution preserves these.

Comment: What is a *parametric exponential distribution family* ? $span(\{ e^{-n(x-a)} 1_{x-a > 0},a\in \Bbb{R},n>0\})$ is dense in $L^1$

Comment: @reuns it's a family of distributions $f(x;\theta)$ with parameter $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that there are functions $h, \eta, T, A$ with $f(x;\theta) = h(x) \exp{(\eta(x) T(\theta) - A(\theta))}$. You can read about these here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential%20family the family you suggest is not such a family

Comment: Also, can you expand on how the closure of this family is dense? This could help find something else. (I'll quickly repeat that the question is about _convolutions_, not mixtures, so weighted sums of distributions are not relevant)